# Hotstrings don't trigger after deleting text

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

I have a weird problem regarding hotstrings:

Everytime I delete any *non-hotstring* word by using either

`ctrl` + `a`, `backspace`

or

`ctrl` + `backspace`

(I will now call them §),

all hotstrings will no longer trigger after that (tested in different applications).
They somehow work again when I insert a whitespace character like `space` or `enter` before I write the next hotstring.

This problem does *not* occur if I...

- delete a working hotstring (also using §)
- delete a non-hotstring word by just using `backspace` repeatedly

Note: my test script for this is just one line:

```
:*:bzw::beziehungsweise
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?
(I'm using AHK version 1.1.29.01 on Windows 8.1)

Comment: I am unable to recreate this issue. When I run the same test script and type `bzq` it replaces it with `beziehungsweise`. I then `ctrl + backspace` and type `bzq` and the string is replaced correctly. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: Did you mean "bzw" in both cases?
If I type `bzq` (which shouldn't trigger the hotstring), then `ctrl + backspace`, and then type `bzw` (which should work), nothing happens.

If however I type `bzw`,  which triggers the hotrstring, and then use `ctrl + backspace` on "beziehungsweise", hotsttrings *will work* after that.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tested with the `bzw` let me retest that.  Edit: Yes I am seeing the same issue. No clue on the fix doing some reading.

Comment: Hey, wanted to share this site as well. Ive posted on both stack and the AHK forums before to get help, might not hurt in this case as well. https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewforum.php?f=5&sid=3732597b486cfad96e86106509b0d6f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backspace doesn't reset the hotstring recognizer. When you type `bzq` followed by `ctrl` + `backspace` Autohotkey isn't ready to interpret the input as a new hotstring. To reset hotstring recognizer use `Hotstring("Reset")` [(https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm#Reset)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm#Reset). In my scripts I deal with `ctrl` + `backspace` in the following way:

```
Ctrl & Backspace::
    SendInput ^`b
    Hotstring("Reset")
Return
```